# Display foreign key linked models in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have three models I would like to display with in a treeview

```
 Event Market
           Runner
           Runner
           Runner
      Market
           Runner
           Runner
```

Event can have multiple markets and markets can have multiple runners. 
I would like to be able to get fetch these models from one api request to view and delete old events if necessary.

I've tried to create a combined serialiser but I get an error saying url name not valid with Runner. I don't think it's right referencing Runner model in the combined serializer as the Runner url has changed to the same name as combined.

```
{
    "events": "http://localhost:8000/api/events/",
    "markets": "http://localhost:8000/api/markets/",
    "runners": "http://localhost:8000/api/combined/",
    "balance": "http://localhost:8000/api/balance/",
    "combined": "http://localhost:8000/api/combined/"
}
```

What is the best way to go about this?

```
class Event(models.Model):
    sport_id = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    event_id = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=13)


class Market(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    market_id = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    market_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    volume = models.FloatField(null=True)

class Runner(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    runner_id = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    back_odds = models.FloatField(null=True)
    lay_odds = models.FloatField(null=True)


class CombinedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    event = EventSerializer()
    market = MarketSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Runner
        fields = ('id','runner_name','runner_id', 'name', 'event' ,'market')


class CombinedViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, 
                     viewsets.GenericViewSet, 
                     mixins.RetrieveModelMixin):

   queryset = Runner.objects.all()
   serializer_class = CombinedSerializer
```

Comment: easiest way is to make a method in model (with self only param) and to link serializer to this method by the method name as to the usual model param

Comment: I don't really understand what your saying. Can you show me?

Answer (score 0):

from your model, you have a double dependency for runners from the event and from the market, both null=True, code below to build a tree likes:

```
event:[
    runners:[
      runnner1 (not market dependable)
      ...
      runnnerx (not market dependable)
      ]
    markets:[
        maket1:[
            runner1
            ...
            runnery
        ],
       market2:[
           ...]
```

## serializer

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model Event
        fields: ('id','event_id', 'event_name', 'runners', 'markets')
```

## model at the end of Event class (inside class) add

```
def runners(self):
    runners  = Runner.objects.filter(event=self, market__isnull=True)
    return [{"runner_id": runner.runner_id, "name": runner.name} for runner in runners]

def markets(self):
    markets  = Market.objects.filter(event=self)
    return [{"market_id": market.market_id, "market_name": market.market_name, "runners":[{"runner_id": runner.runner_id, "name": runner.name} for runner in Runner.objects.filter(event=self, market=market)]} for market in markets]
```

## views - simple view with GET (list) options

Sorry for typos or simple drawbacks - was typing right here